# Does CSR 4.0 Bluetooth Chip Works in Elementry OS?

Tags: bluetooth

I am using this chip and this is the reason I am not using linux i tried this on Ubuntu/Elementry OS / Zorin OS but it does not work.

If CSR 4.0 Is supported in Elementry OS it would be really cool.

This is the Chip/Dongle.
[image: CSR 4.0 Chip]

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately a picture doesn’t have the 8 characters needed to answer your question accurately. Could you:(1) insert the device into an available USB port (2) open Terminal (3) type `sudo lsusb` (to list all USB devices) (4) [edit] your question to include the output. This will make it possible to answer your question 

Comment: Your device does not work because [it is most likely a clone](https://www.reddit.com/r/AnnePro/comments/e76ij8/csr_40_bluetooth_dongle_on_linux/)